# Whether the tangent space can be saw as $M\times R^m$?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth differential n-dim manifold, $TM$ is the tangent space ,I think the $TM$ can be treated as $M\times R^m$ ,whether it is right ?

Comment: You're asking whether the tangent bundle is trivial. It usually isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the tangent space is not $M\times R^n$ unless the manifold is parallelizable.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelizable_manifold

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

It is not easy, but I suggest you to visualize $T\mathbb{S}^{2}$ and why it is not the same as $\mathbb{S}^{2}\times \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Then you can try to visualize $T\mathbb{RP}^{2}$. Note that $T\mathbb{S}^{1}\cong \mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{R}^{1}$, so one way of thinking about it is that you can try to glue the two pieces over the equator.